# Typsescript Select show the wrong value

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, ionic2

I have this code:

```
<select #C (change)="changeSelect(zone.id, C.value)">
  <option *ngFor="let town of townsLocal" [attr.value]="town.data" [attr.selected]="town.data === zone.town && 'selected'">
    {{town.name}}
  </option>
</select>
```

The code is pretty simple but the select box show me the last entry in townslocal instead of the selected one. The attribute selected work well, select return me the good value but the display isn't good.

If i delete the [attr.selected] attribute, the first entry is displayed.

What am i doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried it with [value] instead of [attr.value]?

Comment: And what should `town.data === zone.town && 'selected'` do?? A logical and between a bool and a string? No idea what would be the result with JS type coercions, and it might even be interpreted different in angular.

Comment: town.data and zone.town are both strings like "America/New_York"
Basically this means:
A and b are strings, B is changing with the ng for and if B == A put a selected attribute on the option tag else put nothing

Comment: If they are comparing them will yield a bool. Why add `&& 'selected'` behind that? What should `true && 'selected'` perform?

Comment: I think you just want `[attr.selected]="town.data === zone.town"`. And I think the `attr.` part is here also unnecessary or even wrong.

Comment: Thank you for the help, i've found the good answer and posted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oooh, i found why it behave like this.
I need to use

`[attr.selected]="town.data === zone.town && 'selected' || null"`

Else it put some selected="false" tags on each of my options and ionic seems to do not like it

Thanks